# Unable to work out the "setTimeout" function accordingly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, settimeout, mouseover, mouseout

## Code :

```js
function mouseSlideIn() {
  document.getElementById("box").style =
    "background: blue; height: 50px; width: 50px;";
}

function mouseSlideOut() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("box").style = "";
    document.getElementById("eventDiv").style = "";
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
  margin: 0;
}

#eventDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  background: powderblue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 0.8s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

#box {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

```html
<br>
<center>
  <div id="eventDiv" onmouseover="mouseSlideIn()" onmouseout="mouseSlideOut()">
    <div id="box"></div>
    <!--Above is the red box i.e. inside the main DIV-->
  </div>
</center>
```

## Goal :

1. When I hover over the `id="eventDIV"` (outer most div), the `id="box"` must shrink and change color.
2. When I hover **out** of the `id="eventDIV"` , the `id="box"` must return to its original size & color.
3. But, before the box returns to its original state, I want a delay of (let's say `2000ms` ).
4. This is achievable with the help of `setTimeout` function.

## Problems :

1. When I hover **out** of the `id="eventDIV"` before the `setTimeout` runs out which is `2000ms` , it breaks the code.
2. It doesn't run appropriately when I hover **over** again (i.e.): Even when the cursor is inside the `id="eventDIV"` , the `mouseSlideOut()` function gets executed, which was supposed to be called on `onmouseout` event; that is when I hover **out**.
3. It keeps repeating the same mistake until I ***refresh*** the code.

## What have I tried :

1. I have tried using `clearTimeout` function, but its doesn't seems to help.
2. Some other methods that didn't work.

---

**Note:**

- I am a novice in JS.
- I don't want any changes in CSS/pseudo elements ( `:hover` ).
- I want to try it through JS (if possible).
- This is just practice code, I am going to implement this elsewhere (if it works).
- Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show how you used clearTimeout....

`let timer;

function mouseSlideIn() {
   clearTimeout(timer); ...
}

timer = setTimeout(()=> {}, 2000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the clearTimeout-function. As you can also see in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout), you need to set an ID for your timeout to be able to clear it.

This should do the trick:

```js
let timeoutId;

function mouseSlideIn() {
  document.getElementById("box").style =
    "background: blue; height: 50px; width: 50px;";
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}

function mouseSlideOut() {
  timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById("box").style = "";
    document.getElementById("eventDiv").style = "";
  }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Answer :

```js
function mouseSlideIn() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  document.getElementById("box").style =
    "background: blue; height: 50px; width: 50px;";
}

let timer;

function mouseSlideOut() {
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("box").style = "";
    document.getElementById("eventDiv").style = "";
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
  margin: 0;
}

#eventDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  background: powderblue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 0.8s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

#box {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

```html
<br>
<center>
  <div id="eventDiv" onmouseover="mouseSlideIn()" onmouseout="mouseSlideOut()">
    <div id="box"></div>
    <!--Above is the red box i.e. inside the main DIV-->
  </div>
</center>
<br>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).